# Ad-hoc override of ASP.NET maximum request size

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to override the maximum request size for a specific ASP.NET/ASP.NET MVC page, **without** also changing it for the rest of the website via `Web.config`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use <location> element in web.config and define the setting for your page url.

Comment: Who's that and how did I beat out him? I'm new here, registered just today... :D

Comment: I didn't realize you were new to the site. Ignore my previous comment. You are doing great for your first day!